# AS3 - Access of undefined property (Static variable)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to change a static variable in the class's constructor. At the start I have:

```
public static var mainReference:Main;
public static var timerReference:Timer;
public var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
```

This is so my static functions can access main and timer. At Main's constructor I have:

```
mainReference = this;
timerReference = timer;
```

The problem is, the first gives no error when I compile it, but the second tells me Access of undefined property (timerReference).

Comment: What if you do timerReference = new Timer(1000) in the constructor instead?

Comment: Why? Initializing a static variable in every instance of a class doesn't sound like a very good idea to me.

Comment: @RIAstar Surely OP is not doing this with every class. I bet he just want a global access to the document class, just like a singleton. However `timerReference` is pretty useless since `timer` is public, making it possible to access it by doing `Main.mainReference.timer`.

Comment: @ancide: Oh! I have never thought of that! Thanks

Comment: @Ancide @Marty If the OP is doing this only with the first instance of the class, then the program becomes dependent on order of instantiation. Next developer comes in; he unknowingly changes the order in which objects are created; the program breaks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might have something to do that the flash player is trying to access `timerReference` as a class var instead of a static var.

Try this:

```
this.mainReference = this;
Main.timerReference = this.timer;
```

Now you are telling flash player to explicitly access `mainReference` as a class var and `timerReference` as a static class var.